# blank space to make the user add the text on PDFKIT

Tags: ios, swift, pdfkit

I use a `pdfkit` and I want to add a blank space to make the user add the text he wants in the space that I put but I did not know how to do this and in fact I searched a lot and could not find an explanation for its work Can anyone help me

[PDFKIT Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7kfp.png)

Comment: Where is this space supposed to go on the document?? Also, is white space really a good idea for a token area for a user to edit? Can you use something more obvious like "[]" or "{}".

Comment: do you know how can i add like this ? i think they are use a `adobe acrobat reader`